# ActiveMQ: Can we send multiple files using single message

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I want to send a few Strings, a few integers and a few files via ActiveMQ messages ? Is it possible ? I am aware of BlobMessages, ByteMessage and ObjectMessages but none of them seems to be answer my question.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Why do none of the existing message types work? Why can't you just stuff all the data you want into a single message?

Comment: But how ? Strings and integers can be managed by many ways, but how do I put multiple files in a single message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) comes to mind as a possible solution. Put your data into JSON objects, turn the JSON into a string, and stuff it into a TextMessage or turn the string into bytes and stuff it into a BytesMessage. You might run into problems with the ultimate size of the message. If so, you might want to move to [ActiveMQ Artemis which supports arbitrarily large messages](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/large-messages.html).